# Import categories and products on prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm developing a php script to import and keep synced a prestashop database with data coming from a management software.

Is it a good method to insert data directly on the database or is it better to use the prestashop classes.

Can you give an exemple how to import categories with class method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$category = new Category;
$category->id = 155;
$category->active = 0;
$category->id_parent = 15;
$category->name = "category";
$category->link_rewrite = "one-category";
//this will force ObjectModel to use your ID
$_GET['forceIDs'] = true;
$category->add();
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I already did that and it works like a charm. now I'm tring to upload various images to products. I have them in a folder inside /img and I need to make a script to change the names and put them in the right place. Do you know the prestashop to do that?

Comment: you  have to make another post for that problem, i have the answer but in the comments the number of characters is limited.

Comment: Thank you guys I fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It's much reliable to use classes to reach your goal. Because you avoid all issues which can occur if versions of your prestashop instances will be different. With classes, you won't damage a database and won't confuse your data and also during the import, all data will be validated by classes. The example above seems to be correct and depends only on the number of fields that you want to import

*Copied above*

```
$category = new Category;
$category->id = 155;
$category->active = 0;
$category->id_parent = 15;
$category->name = "category";
$category->link_rewrite = "one-category";
//this will force ObjectModel to use your ID
$_GET['forceIDs'] = true;
$category->add();
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I already did that and it works like a charm. now I'm tring to upload various images to products. I have them in a folder inside /img and I need to make a script to change the names and put them in the right place. Do you know the prestashop to do that?